# How to Create New Field with Specific different Internal Name and Display name in SharePoint 2013 Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

When creating a new field using Fields.AddFieldsAsXml, I used below code :

```
<Field Type='Text' DisplayName='Employee Number' Name='EmpNumber' />
```

But the Internal Name of the created field. `"Name='EmpNumber'"` part of the CAML will be ignored by SharePoint and the created field will have display name `"Employee Number"` and internal name `"Employee_x0020_Number"`.

But I want internal name as a `"EmpNumber"` so how it will be created ?

Comment: Use the following xml format when passing the fieldxml parameter :
var fieldXml = "<Field Type='URL' DisplayName='" + statusFieldName + "' Name='" + statusFieldName + "' />";

Comment: Post your comment as answer so Swati Patil can mark it as the correct answer for the question (and you get points) tnx

Comment: Thanks Karvannan but its not working properly...

Comment: @swatipatil did you solve this? I have the same issue